# convert youtube links to jwplayer embed code

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have a chat and when a person sends a youtube link I would like to instantly convert it to playable video.

So when a user sends a link in the following formats

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLORyXO8mVc`

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLORyXO8mVc&feature=related`

It will convert the link to this code

```
<div id='mediaspace'>Youtube</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'XXXXXX-YOUTUBE-VIDEO-URL-GOES-HERE-XXXXXX',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '350',
    'height': '230'
  });
</script>
```

Also is it possible to only take the youtube link in this format
`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLORyXO8mVc` and any links that a users sends having `&feature` or more attached to it will be remove only having the standard url like this `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLORyXO8mVc`

here is what i came up with but its not working:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var regEx = /http://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?.*v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/;


    $("body").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html().match(regEx);
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regEx, '
        <div id='mediaspace'>Youtube</div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
            'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
            'file': '$1',
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'width': '350',
            'height': '230'
          });
        </script>
        '));
    });
});
```

Comment: What is it that you actually need help with? Do you want help to remove everything but `v` in the URLs variables?

Comment: @Ancide wrap the link in an embed code. i added the code that i have but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Your code had no escaping in the regular expression (you can't use / inside / without escaping), or your replacement string (you can't use ' inside ' without escaping). Try this:

```
var regEx = /http:\/\/(www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?.*v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/;

$("body").filter(function() {
    return $(this).html().match(regEx);
}).each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regEx, "<div id='mediaspace'>Youtube</div><script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({'flashplayer': 'player.swf','file': '$1','controlbar': 'bottom','width': '350','height': '230'});</scr"+"ipt>"));
});
```